# Python multiple class hierarchy __init__ not being executed

Tags: python, django

I'm using django, but this is rather a generic python question.

I have defined a class that I intend to use to extend the ModelForm and Form classes, from django.forms.

The code looks like this:

```
class FormMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ every method ocurrence must call super """
        super(FormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.new_attr = 'This is an attribute'



class ModelFormAdapter(forms.ModelForm):
""" I use this class so __init__ signatures match """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ every method ocurrence must call super """
        super(ModelFormAdapter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)         


class BaseModelForm(ModelFormAdapter, FormMixin):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ BaseModelForm never gets the attribute new_attr """
        super(BaseModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have even debugged this and the FormMixin **init** method is never called. What am I doing wrong? What I want to achieve is to add some attributes to the form and preprocess field labels and css classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because one of `ModelFormAdapter`'s ancestors (`BaseForm`), doesn't call `super`, and the chain breaks. Put `FormMixin` first in the parent list.